# server error in liferay for accessing mail Dependcies

Tags: java, email, liferay-6

SERVER ERROR: Service Unavailable url=https://repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public/javax/mail/mail/1.4/mail-1.4-javadoc.jar

Comment: more version here:
https://repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public/javax/mail/mail/

Comment: I don't see this error. Probably because I don't know what steps you take to get it. Please edit your question to make the whole situation reproducible for someone who doesn't have access to your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the available resources in this repository:

https://repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public/javax/mail/mail/1.4/